# Detect Remote Notifications when application enters foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, appdelegate

Good day, 
I have a question about receiving remote notification on iOS, I know that when a n`-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` will be called if the app is running or if the app is not running and the user taps on the notification.

But, if the user ignore the notification badge in the lock screen and unlock the iPhone, after that you runs the app,then that function will not be called, so how can I get the received notification !!

Thank You :)

Comment: You can not do it.

Comment: if notification is still in notification center then you will got it in didFinishLaunching method

Comment: You should create a way to query the server to see if it has pending notifications

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati, that is false.  It also wouldn't help for the instances when the app was already running, even if you had been correct.

Comment: Your best bet is to send silent push notifications and then generate corresponding local notifications if required

Comment: @Avi, i am just talking about when app is killed.

Comment: @Ahmed,  You will only receive information about the notification that was used to open your app.If you really want this call service API to get same info.

Comment: @kaushal I think that is right, I tried every thing and there is no way to save the notifications locally, but my problem with using the backend is the huge number of rows that will be saved in the database, we have more that 50K each notification will be saved in the db, I think that does not make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the phone is locked, the application is sent to an inactive state by the OS.
So the notifications received during this time are as good as notifications received when the app is in the background.
And just like any notification received in the background, the app won't get control unless the user taps on the notification in the tray.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore the notification from notification center then you can't get it inside application.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using following code

```
 NSDictionary *pushNotificationPayload = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if(pushNotificationPayload)
    {
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:pushNotificationPayload];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For any condition , check whether user has tapped, or app is in background or is active.
You just have to check the application state in

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {

        //app is currently active, can update badges count here

    }else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){

        //app is in background, if content-available key of your notification is set to 1, poll to your backend to retrieve data and update your interface here

    }else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive){

        //app is transitioning from background to foreground (user taps notification), do what you need when user taps here

    }
```